# Django get query execution time

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-views, django-orm

Is there a way to measure Django query time without using [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar)? It is not for debugging/logging, I need it to display on the webpage like `about # results (# seconds)`.

Edit: I need this feature in production mode, so `DEBUG=True` is not an option

Comment: I didn't read Victor's comment as unfriendly (and there is a smiley...). It's also a reasonable point to make (ie. why isn't the wall clock time satisfactory).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although `django.db.connection.queries` will give you the query times it only works when `DEBUG=True`. For using it for general purposes we can work with [Database instrumentation [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/instrumentation/) and write a wrapper that will time our queries. Below is the example directly from the above documentation which I would say seems to fit your need:

```
import time

class QueryLogger:

    def __init__(self):
        self.queries = []

    def __call__(self, execute, sql, params, many, context):
        current_query = {'sql': sql, 'params': params, 'many': many}
        start = time.monotonic()
        try:
            result = execute(sql, params, many, context)
        except Exception as e:
            current_query['status'] = 'error'
            current_query['exception'] = e
            raise
        else:
            current_query['status'] = 'ok'
            return result
        finally:
            duration = time.monotonic() - start
            current_query['duration'] = duration
            self.queries.append(current_query)
```

To use this you would make your queries in such a way:

```
from django.db import connection

query_logger = QueryLogger()

with connection.execute_wrapper(query_logger):
    # Make your queries here

for query in query_logger.queries:
    print(query['sql'], query['duration'])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the info in `django.db.connection.queries`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

if `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`, you can see your database queries (and times) using:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.queries
```

**P.s**: There is a package called [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) which helps you so much to see your queries and timings and so on ... . I recommend to use it instead of `connection.queries`.

Comment: I need this 'feature' to be in production server, so `DEBUG=True` is not an option for me. Anyways, thanks for the effort!