# get db utilization of a mysql query

Tags: mysql, django

Is there any way/command to get DB utilization of a query i.e.., how much memory of DB it used, how much time it took to execute.. and all. so, that I can plan and further optimize the query

I tried to google it but I can only find ways to get CPU utilization (application level memory usage) but didn't find anything related to DB utilization

I'm using Mysql DB and Django

Comment: Does it help for execution time? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68194120/5559590

Comment: It does, to get execution time. but my major concern is to get DB utilization of query

Comment: Within Performance Schema available data many details may be uncovered.  See this URL to get started.  https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/performance-schema-great-power-comes-without-great-cost/   For an elementary quick check on io requirements of a specific query see this URL by Rick James (one of our best resources)  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory - No.  Most of the memory is "shared" in some sense, so it is not possible to isolate memory usage to a single query or even a single connection.

Speed -- The slowlog will provide elapsed time and a few other statistics about any "slow" query.  The default `long_query_time = 10` (seconds) needs to be changed when you turn it on.

If you come back with a particular query that you need help on, please provide the query, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  (No, we are not good at optimizing at the framework (Django) level.)